# Implemented train function in PyTorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I'm building models of neural networks for some experiments. I use PyTorch and each time I train a model I use the following code:

```
def train_and_evaluate(net, optimizer, criterion):
    start_time = time.time()
    train_losses, test_losses, train_acc, test_acc = [], [], [], []
    # net.double()

    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        epoch_start_time = time.time()
        running_loss_train, running_loss_test = 0.0, 0.0
        total, correct, test_total, test_correct = 0, 0, 0, 0

        # Train mode
        net.train()

        #Loop batches
        for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):

            if use_cuda and torch.cuda.is_available():
                images = images.cuda()
                labels = labels.cuda()

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = net(images.detach())
            # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            running_loss_train += loss.item()

            # Calculate training accuracy for epoch
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1) # Get th
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

        # Calculate test loss and accuracy for epoch
        net.eval()
        with torch.no_grad():
            for images, labels in test_loader:

                if use_cuda and torch.cuda.is_available():
                    images = images.cuda()
                    labels = labels.cuda()

                outputs = net(images)
                test_loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
                running_loss_test += test_loss.item()

                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                test_total += labels.size(0)
                test_correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

            if (epoch + 1) % 10 == 0 or epoch == 0:
                print(f'Epoch [{epoch+1:02d}/{num_epochs}]\tTime: {time.time() - epoch_start_time:.2f}\tTrain Loss: {(running_loss_train / len(train_loader)):.4f}\tTrain Acc: {(correct / total):.0%}\tTest Loss: {running_loss_test / len(test_loader):.4f}\tTest Accuracy: {(test_correct / test_total):.0%}'.expandtabs(4))

            train_losses.append(running_loss_train / len(train_loader))
            test_losses.append(running_loss_test / len(test_loader))
            train_acc.append(correct / total)
            test_acc.append(test_correct / test_total)

    print(f'Training time: {(time.time() - start_time)/60:5.2f} min.')
    return train_losses, test_losses, train_acc, test_acc
```

I simply copy and paste it from other projects and I find it redundant to use that same code each time, it is useful almost in every model I test and usually looks quite similar. I wonder if there is a shortcut or some module with implementation of this function to reduce number of code lines and make it more readable. Something like:

```
model = NeuralNetwork()
train_losses, test_losses, train_acc, test_acc = train(model,
                                                       epochs=50,
                                                       verbose=True,
                                                       cuda=True,
                                                       optimizer=optimizer,
                                                       criterion=criterion)
```

That I could just pass the parameters for training and not explicitly 'write' the code evey time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#modules)

Save `train_and_evaluate` function into python file. The file name is the module name with the suffix `.py` appended. for Ex.: `model_util.py`

Now you can access `train_and_evaluate` function using importing `model_util` module. like

```py
import model_util

model = NeuralNetwork()
train_losses, test_losses, train_acc, test_acc = model_util.train_and_evaluate(...)
```

Comment: Thanks, that will certainly help. Though I thought maybe there is already a function to use from PyTorch or some other package, such that I won't need to move `model_util.py` to different project's folder each time. I guess there is no such function that is already implemented..